# how to parse this output file in Java

Tags: java, file, parsing, testing, output

I have the following out put from a text file:

===============================================

```
guideMenuSuite.mts:
[monkeytalk:run] MonkeyTalk v1.0.11.beta5c_473 - 2012-07-18 11:38:51 MDT - Copyright 2012 Gorilla Logic, Inc. - www.gorillalogic.com
[monkeytalk:run] running suite guideMenuSuite.mts...
[monkeytalk:run] BCOKAS127271: -start suite (1 test)
[monkeytalk:run] BCOKAS127271:   1 : guide_menu.mt
[monkeytalk:run] BCOKAS127271:   -> OK
[monkeytalk:run] BCOKAS127271: -end suite
[monkeytalk:run] result: OK
[monkeytalk:run] ...done
```

================================================

In Java, I need to:
1) Parse the out put for the device serial number (BCOKAS127271 in this case.... it changes depending on what device is being tested).
2) Get the status results of the test which is after the -> (-> OK in this case).

I tried using split but the data keeps coming out null...

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

here is my code:

CODE

```
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    maintextarea.append(strLine + "\n");
                    System.out.println(strLine);
                    System.out.flush();
                    maintextarea.append(selectedSerial);
                    delims = "[ \\->]+";
                    //String[] tokens = strLine.split(delims);
                    //String[] tokens = strLine.substring(prefix.length()).split(delims);

                    String noprefixStr = strLine.substring(strLine.indexOf(prefix) + prefix.length());
                    String[] tokens = noprefixStr.split(delims);

                    //for (String t: tokens)
                    {
                        //System.out.println(t);

                            if (tokens.toString().contains("ERROR"))
                            {
                                testStatus = "ERROR";
                                maintextarea.append("\n" + selectedValue + " " + selectedSerial + " = " + testStatus + "\n");
                                System.out.println(selectedValue + " " + selectedSerial + " = " + testStatus);
                                System.out.flush();
                            }

                            else if (tokens.toString().contains("FAILURE"))
                            {
                                testStatus = "FAILED";
                                maintextarea.append("\n" + selectedValue + " " + selectedSerial + " = " + testStatus + "\n");
                                System.out.println(selectedValue + " " + selectedSerial + " = " + testStatus);
                                System.out.flush();
                            }

                            else if (tokens.toString().contains("OK"))
                            {
                                testStatus = "PASSED";
                                maintextarea.append("\n" + selectedValue + " " + selectedSerial + " = " + testStatus + "\n");
                                System.out.println(selectedValue + " " + selectedSerial + " = " + testStatus);
                                System.out.flush();
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                testStatus = "N/A";
                                maintextarea.append("\n" + selectedValue + " " + selectedSerial + " = " + testStatus + "\n");
                                System.out.println(selectedValue + " " + selectedSerial + " = " + testStatus);
                                System.out.flush();
                            }

                    }


                }


                br.close();
```

============================================================

UPDATE:

I found my solution based on all the input that I received from this group!
I ended up making it really simple and parsing the out put file for an expression and then based on that setting a variable to pass or fail or error.

Here is the base code I used:

```
try 
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("/home/ironmantis7x/Documents/TWC_test/MT_test_runner_output.txt"))));
            String strLine;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (strLine.contains("-> OK"))
                {
                    testStatus = "Pass";
                    System.out.println("Test Result = " + testStatus);
                }

            }
        } 

        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(parseFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Sorry it took me so long to get back to you guys and say thanks!

ironmantis7x

Comment: Show us the code that you tried.

Comment: Is this the standard output format. I mean all your output file comes this way. if yes then it would be easy.

Comment: @smit -- yes this is standard out put format that I directed to a text file...

Comment: You will have to iterate over the file one line at a time.  You will have to parse each line separately by searching for various patterns and strings.  If you show us your code (rather than saying "_I tried split_") we can help you fix it.  Otherwise, people aren't going to write your program for you (at least I hope they won't).

Comment: @jahroy: not trying to get anyone to write it for me ... I am new to Java and I am just trying to get help ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import java.util.Pattern
import java.util.Matcher

Pattern status = Pattern.compile("\\[.*] \\w+:\\s+-> (\w+).*");

...
```

You can learn how to do it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html)